# Jquery Ajax stop loading after success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, undefined

I am using an jquery script to retrieve some data from an PHP file. The problem is when all data is retrieved, the script is not stopping to execute.

I used console.log to check and I am getting this 1000 undefined and still increment to infinite (99999999+ undefined) i think, how to stop this ?

```
id = 0;
function do_ajax() {

        id++;
        var url = $("#link_" + id).find("a").attr("href");
        console.log(url);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data : {"url" : url},
            url : "analyzer/checkbroken.php",
            success: function(data){
            if(data == "200")
            {
                $("#status_" + id).html(\'<i class="fa fa-check"></i>\');
            } else {
                $("#status_" + id).html(\'<i class="fa fa-times"></i>\');
                $(".linka_" + id).addClass("brokenlink");
            }
            do_ajax();
            }
            });
        };




do_ajax();
```

Comment: When do you want it to stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are calling the function `do_ajax()` recursively so the code run to infinity.
You can try put an if condition to stop the increment of `i`.

Comment: I tried this but still the same: `if (url !== null || url !== undefined) {`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `do_ajax()` call function within the success function of the AJAX call. That's causing the infinte loop.

Comment: If I removed then script will get only the first data not all.

Comment: If there are N html tags that have the pattern 'link_NUMBER' as their ID it means the request will be called N times. What are you trying to do? Pagination? I think you could come up with a better solution for this. It's poor performance. Plus, I can see you're not doing anything with the data sent by the server (in case the server sends something back).

Comment: I have a fixed table with fixed links and I need to verify each one if is broken or not, and to display the fa icon if is valid or not. the script is working. but the infinite loop is not good I think.

Comment: I don't see a condition in which the loop finishes. You should check if the var url = $("#link_" + id).find("a").attr("href") tag exists, if it doesn't exists it means the algorithm has come to an end, therefore you don't need to do the ajax call anymore. Am I right?